# Android Tab height wastes real estate! There must be a way to minimize it!

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am not using an image icon, only a (fixed size) text indicator. How do I set the tab height to its most efficient size?[wrap_content has no effect.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `setIndicator` method to set the view that should be displayed inside the tab. This will allow you to use a custom view

[TabHost docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html)

Comment: @gssi please click the check mark if my solution has helped you.      @I82Much sorry about the link, its the TabSpec's setIndicator(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(android.view.View)

Answer (score 2):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 35;
```

Comment: Ouch, setting dimensions to absolute values could be an issue here right? How would that scale on super small phones, or large tables?

Comment: How large a table are we talking about?